# PDF difference between k and scn color fill

Tags: pdf

To set the fill color in PDF there are these three ways:

```
247 28 36 rg
3 89 86 0 k
0.03 0.89 0.86 0.0 scn
```

`... rg` is RGB, `... k` is CMYK, and `... scn` is SetAdvancedColor(?). Other than being as a decimal rather than a percentage, what is the difference between `k` and `scn`?

---

*Useful links for other beginners: [How to decompress PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106866/849697), ['PDF Succinctly' book on PDF structure](https://www.slideshare.net/suhee_0425/pdf-succinctly)*

Comment: "`scn`: Same as SC but also supports Pattern, Separation, DeviceN and ICCBased colour spaces". Useful link for a command reference: [PDF 32000-1:2008](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (PDF). This is on p. 172.

Comment: @usr2564301 How about making that an actual answer?

Comment: Should I change the question to 'PDF difference between k and sc color fill' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k` and `rg` are shortcuts for the `DeviceCMYK` and `DeviceRGB` color spaces respectively. To use `sc` or `scn` you need to specify the color space using `cs` operator.

For example.

```
1.0 0.0 1.0 rg
```

is shorthand for

```
/DeviceRGB cs
1.0 0.0 1.0 sc
```