# PrawnPDF text as CMYK color

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn, cmyk

When creating a PDF using PrawnPDF with code:

```
d = Prawn::Document.new( page_size: [595,842] )
d.text( 'hello world', color: [3, 89, 86, 0] )
d.render
```

And then [decompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106866/849697) the PDF and inspecting the contents, there should only be `/DeviceCMYK CS` in there but there are also `/DeviceRGB CS` in there also.

Trying to get everything CMYK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `fill_color` and the `stroke_color` won't affect the visual appearance in the PDF, but it will mean that there are no longer any pesky RGB references in the PDF

```
d = Prawn::Document.new( page_size: [595,842] )
d.fill_color [3, 89, 86, 0]
d.stroke_color [3, 89, 86, 0]
d.text( 'hello world', color: [3, 89, 86, 0] )
d.render
```